# Template class as template class parameter

Tags: c++, templates

In this example I create a Functor class taking functions as parameters. The second functor shall take an object of the first functor as template parameter and call a function of the first functor. I am not sure how the template for the second Functor must look.

This is the first Functor, which is working as expected:

```
typedef float (*pDistanceFu) (float, float);
typedef float (*pDecayFu) (float, float, float);

template <pDistanceFu Dist, pDecayFu Rad, pDecayFu LRate>
class DistFunction {    
public:
  DistFunction() {}
  DistFunction(char *cstr) : name(cstr) {};

  char *name;
  float distance(float a, float b) { return Dist(a,b); };
  float rad_decay(float a, float b, float c) { return Rad(a,b,c); };
  float lrate_decay(float a, float b, float c) { return LRate(a,b,c); };
};
```

Here I create an instance of the functor which is specialized:

```
DistFunction<foo,bar,foobar> fcn_gaussian((char*)"gaussian");
```

Here I don't know how the template has to look, to take any type of DistFunction<...> as parameter

```
template<template<DistFunction> typename = F>
struct functor {
  float fCycle;
  float fCycles;

  functor(float cycle, float cycles) : fCycle(cycle), fCycles(cycles) {}

  float operator()(float lrate) {
    return (F.lrate_decay)(lrate, fCycle, fCycles);
  }
};
```

How I want to use the second functor:

```
typedef DistFunction<foo,bar,foobar> gaussian;
void test() {
  functor<gaussian> test(0,1);
}
```

The errors:

```
error: argument list for class template "DistFunction" is missing
error: expected "class"
error: expected a "," or ">"
```

Comment: How will you use `functor`? `functor<what_will_be_specified_here>`?

Comment: Updated the question, probably not possible that the compiler gets the template information from the object.. , I guess

Comment: Who provides the functor object?

Comment: All your `char*` should be `const char*`, and you don't need to cast the literal string then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<DistFunction> typename = F
```

This is an unnamed template template parameter with a single non-type parameter of type `DistFunction` and default value `F`. Since `DistFunction` is not a type (it's a class template) and `F` does not exist, this makes no sense.

You don't need any template template parameters here. The simple

```
template<typename F>
struct functor {
```

should do the job.

If you want to *restrict* `F`, that is, only allow it to accept various instantiations of `DistFunction` and nothing else, you need different language facilities, such as `static_assert` and/or `enable_if`. This is only needed for better error messages in case someone imstantiates `functor` incorrectly. Just use `F` as if it is a `DistFunction`.

Comment: You were right. My mistake was that I forgot the constructor. Making the members static made even my test code work.. I am so dumb.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
template<typename F>
struct functor {
  float fCycle;
  float fCycles;

  functor(float cycle, float cycles) : fCycle(cycle), fCycles(cycles) {}

  float operator()(float lrate) {
    return F((char*)"gaussian").lrate_decay(lrate, fCycle, fCycles);
  }
};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/XYXFVG59812)

Comment: This fails because lrate_decay is unknown. Additionally, I want to avoid runtime creation of DistFunction.

Comment: @dgrat Then you need to create it everytime when call `operator()` of `functor`.

Comment: This demoes nothing, you are not calling `test.operator()`.

Comment: @n.m. I've renamed the variable to `t` and `functor<gaussian> t(0.0f ,1.0f); t(2.0f);`.

Comment: @dgrat The linked demo doesn't fail. If you want to avoid runtine creation of an object of a certain class, don't declare non-static members in this class because you won't be able to access them. Also don't give this class a constructor because you won't be calling it. Remove constructors and `name` from DistFunction, make other members static, access them with this syntax `F::lrate_decay`.